# What's app crypto romantic scam?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

didn't have...and then I could tell he was frustrated because it seemed like he just dripped the conversation. I tried to contact him a few times, I can see that he saw the message, but there was no reply. I have managed to gain a little money through both of these deals...or that's what it looks like, but I don't know how to get it from the crypto exchange back to my bank...Can you help?

Answer (score 8):

It's a scam, any money you have sent or paid in is gone and you will not be able to get it back out again (any "gains" you are being shown are fake to keep you on the hook and paying more). Save copies of the messages, then block the contact and report to the authorities in your jurisdiction.